# How to conver HTML + Javascript to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

I'm trying to convert a HTML page which contains Javascript (that formats certain information after the document is loaded) to PDF, using PHP prefarably.

The javascript code will look something like this:
`$(document).ready(function() {
   formatProfile();
});`
This will format the raw data and replace it to the specific DIV.

However, when I do a render and try to convert it to PDF the DIV remains empty, as if the javascript component is not rendered at all.

I've tried using mpdf, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf and many more but none work as intended. Is there any library that will work or is there any workaround (assuming I still prefer to use the javascript to process and output the results to DIV)?

Comment: try TCPDF php library

Comment: i dont know a html->pdf library that will also interpret js, i would replace the js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) is probably your best bet here. You'll have to install the software on your server, but it gives a nice implementation of webkit in a headless setup so that you can completely render a page, javascript included and then capture the screen output to a PDF.

EDIT:

You might look at [this PHP project](https://github.com/microweber/screen) which wraps the PhantomJS application in a PHP script for easier web screen capture from within PHP.

Comment: I've tried out the demo at http://screen.microweber.com/, some part works, but not all. Apparently those part that does not appear, have AJAX call which pulls additional data from the server prior to populating the DIV container.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://www.tcpdf.org/ . Site providing some good examples and also you can design page layout as your own styles. I think this will solve your issues.

Comment: This would require me to re-code the existing webpage to pdf components before I can convert to PDF, I'd rather load the existing page (say from the url) and convert to PDF without re-coding, is it possible?

Comment: Just go through this link http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps . Its up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

[PDFreactor](http://www.realobjects.com/products/pdfreactor/) 6 can convert HTML to PDF and process the JavaScript. It also provides a PHP wrapper.

Comment: are you kidding? 2400$